# Select alternate column having IGN=0 from the following table using CTE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
Device_Code ign Event_DateTime
-------------------------------
5909    0   49:32.0
5909    0   19:32.0
5909    0   49:32.0
5909    0   18:42.0
5909    1   17:42.0
5909    1   16:42.0
5909    1   16:32.0
5909    1   16:27.0
5909    1   16:22.0
5909    1   15:47.0
5909    1   15:42.0
5909    1   15:24.0
5909    1   15:12.0
5909    1   14:52.0
5909    1   13:53.0
5909    1   13:02.0
5909    1   12:02.0
5909    1   11:18.0
5909    1   11:13.0
5909    1   11:02.0
5909    1   10:02.0
5909    1   09:02.0
5909    1   08:02.0
5909    1   07:31.0
5909    1   07:02.0
5909    1   06:29.0
5909    1   06:24.0
5909    0   06:02.0
5909    1   05:02.0
```

Comment: I wants to select only data having first ign=0 not all of the 0 in IGN

Comment: Hi I need only following data Device_Code ign Event_DateTime
5909 0 49:32.0
5909 1 17:42.0
5909 0 06:02.0
5909 1 05:02.0

Comment: On what basis do you define "first"?  Your comment includes a row that appears twice, one with `IGN=1` then another one with `IGN=1` again.  They can't all 3 be first.  I suggest you fix your question & perhaps better test data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for alternate rows where ign=0 then below script will help you to get desire result :

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT Device_Code,
          ign,
          Event_DateTime,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ign ORDER BY Device_Code) RN 
   FROM TableName
)
SELECT Device_Code,
          ign,
          Event_DateTime
FROM CTE
WHERE RN % 2 = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Jaydip I want 5909    0   49:32.0,5909    1   17:42.0,5909    0   06:02.0